# python 3.5 checkbox value not correct

Tags: checkbox, tkinter, python-3.5

I wrote a code in python 3.5 with tkinter and I'm having problems with getting the correct values from the current state (True/False) of the checkboxes.
from some reason I don't always the correct value.
This is a small part of my code that produces the problem:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

# go button event listener
def goButtonCallBack():
    global show_skeleton_whole_body, show_skeleton_no_legs
    show_skeleton_whole_body = var_whole_body.get()
    show_skeleton_no_legs = var_no_legs.get()
    if show_skeleton_whole_body==False and show_skeleton_no_legs==False:
        messagebox.showinfo("Try again", "You must choose one of the options!")
        return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    top = tk.Tk()
    top.geometry("650x550")
    var_whole_body = tk.IntVar()
    checkbox_whole_body = tk.Checkbutton(top, text = "Whole Body", variable = var_whole_body, \
                     onvalue = True, offvalue = False, height=5, \
                     width = 200)

    show_skeleton_whole_body = var_whole_body.get()
    print ('main before select: show_skeleton_whole_body')
    print (show_skeleton_whole_body)

    checkbox_whole_body.select()

    show_skeleton_whole_body = var_whole_body.get()
    print ('main after select: show_skeleton_whole_body')
    print (show_skeleton_whole_body)

    checkbox_whole_body.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    checkbox_whole_body.place(x=15, y=200, width=100)

    var_no_legs= tk.IntVar()
    checkbox_no_legs = tk.Checkbutton(top, text = "  No Legs", variable = var_no_legs, \
                     onvalue = True, offvalue = False, height=4, \
                     width = 200)

    show_skeleton_no_legs = var_no_legs.get()
    print ('main before select: show_skeleton_no_legs')
    print (show_skeleton_no_legs)

    checkbox_no_legs.select()

    show_skeleton_no_legs = var_no_legs.get()
    print ('main after select: show_skeleton_no_legs')
    print (show_skeleton_no_legs)


    checkbox_no_legs.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    checkbox_no_legs.place(x=15, y=250, width=100)


    # create the 'go' button
    bluebutton = tk.Button(top, text="go! >", fg="blue", command=goButtonCallBack)
    bluebutton.place(x=90, y=400)

    # instruction
    instructionsString = "bla bla bla"
    instructionsLabel = tk.Label(top, text=instructionsString, width=500, font=("Helvetica", 9))
    instructionsLabel.pack()
    instructionsLabel.place(x=15, y=450, width=500)

    top.mainloop()
    print('This is the end of the program!!')
```

for some reason the select() command didn't change the value from 0 to 1.
if you run the code and press the 'go' button a message box will appear saying that one of the checkboxes should be checked but they are both checked!
anybody knows what the problem is?

Thanks
David

Comment: Please create an MCVE (http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When I run the above code, it seems to work just fine. After the call to `select` the values changed to 1 (one). It's odd, though, that you set the values to `True` and `False` but seem to actually want the values to be zero and one.

Comment: Thanks Bryan. It's interesting what you're saying since the code worked before and now all of a sudden it doesn't. I thought maybe I changed something and didn't notice. but anyway, the code doesn't work for me. the select command is not changing the value to 1. will it help if I send you all the code?

Comment: No, what will help is to post an MCVE. Part of the process of building the MCVE is to help _you_ distill the problem down to its essence. Often, that process will make the problem and solution self-evident.

Comment: OK. I hope I understood you correctly since it's my first time I post here. You meant that I'll post the smallest code that can be run and still produces the problem right? so here's the code. I made it the smallest as possible. if you run it and then press the "go" button, a message box will appear saying that you must choose one of the options (the checkboxes). but both checkboxes are checked. I have no idea where is the problem.

Here's a link for the code:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8dIZzDbsYEGUm1mVkdoNTVHQmc/view?usp=sharing

sorry but I didn't find a way to attach the code.

Comment: There should be an "edit" button below your question. Please edit the question and put the code there.

Comment: OK. I edited my original question and put the code there.

Comment: I can't duplicate the problem, It works fine for me on OSX and linux.

Comment: I ran it on Windows.
I just checked it and it's very strange. it works fine if I run it through command line. but it doesn't work if I run it through spider.
and I need to run it through spider because I need to debug it.
any idea what can be the problem?